# Why does hasOneThrough display inappropriate data?

Tags: php, laravel

In this example, I get a valid array, but with a nested array that has inconsistencies

```
{ "order_id": 1, "status": 20, 
"product_id": [ 
{ "id": 1, "order_id": 1, "product_id": 8, "quantity": 1, "price": 141 }, 
{ "id": 2, "order_id": 1, "product_id": 30, "quantity": 2, "price": 509 }, 
{ "id": 3, "order_id": 1, "product_id": 21, "quantity": 1, "price": 399 } ], 
"name": { "id": 1, "name": "Product_1", ... "laravel_through_key": 1 }
```

since there are three products in the first order, in the second order I already get "name": "Product_4" i.e. the interval is correct, and the order is in the order of the prods table, not in the order_products table:

```
{ "order_id": 2, "status": 10, 
"product_id": [ 
{ "id": 4, "order_id": 2, "product_id": 1, "quantity": 3, "price": 320 }, 
{ "id": 5, "order_id": 2, "product_id": 11, "quantity": 2, "price": 953 }, 
{ "id": 6, "order_id": 2, "product_id": 20, "quantity": 1, "price": 911 } ], 
"name": { "id": 4, "name": "Product_4", ... "laravel_through_key": 2 }
```

How can I make the product names correspond to product_id in order_products?

here is my table diagram:

```
orders
id - integer
status - integer

order_products
id - integer
order_id - integer
product_id - integer
quantity - integer
price - integer

prods
id - integer
name - string
```

**model Order**

```
class Order extends Model
{
public function order_product()
  {
return $this->hasMany('App\Order_product');
   }

public function prod()
  {
return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Prod', 'App\Order_product', 'order_id', 'id', 'id' );
  }
```

**model Prod**

```
class Prod extends Model
{
public function order()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'order_products');
  }

модель Order_product
class Order_product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price'];
}
```

**Resource Order**

```
class Order extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'order_id'     => $this->id,
            'status'       => $this->status,
            'product_id'   => $this->order_product,
            'name'         => $this->prod,
          ];
    }
```

**controller Order**

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
public function index()
  {
    $orders = Order::with(['order_product', 'prod'])->get();
    return OrderResource::collection($orders);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your DB design, it suppose to be `belongsToMany` between order, and product.

**Order model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prod', 'Order_product', 'order_id','product_id');
}
```

**Product Model**

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'Order_product','product_id', 'order_id');
}
```